# Convert URL params (inline and after ?) to object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I'm looking at creating a vanilla JavaScript function which creates an object of parameters from URL path definition given a specific URL path. Very similar to how AngularJS does it as part of the [routeParams](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js) service. For example...

Given the following path definition:

```
/page1/{id}
```

And the actual URL path of:

```
/page1/23?fname=Jon&lname=Doe
```

I would like to create the following object:

```
{
   "id": 23,
   "fname": "Jon",
   "lname": "Doe"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google `javascript query string` and replace `{id}` with a regex of `\w+`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PT5BG/4/

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thank you for the quick reply. How would that get me the value id? I could certainly find 23 but I wouldn't know the key should be id.

Comment: @DipenShah not sure what helps very much, I need the solution to be in vanilla javascript. Thank you.

Comment: @LeonRevill You did not mention that in your original post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I was looking for. It is a very rough example and the code could obviously be optimised and cleaned up however.

```
function getParams(route, path) {
  var result = {};
  var queryString = (path.indexOf("?") > -1) ? path.substr(path.indexOf("?") + 1, path.length) : null;
  queryString.split("&").forEach(function(part) {
    if(!part) return;
    part = part.replace("+"," ");
    var eq = part.indexOf("=");
    var key = eq>-1 ? part.substr(0,eq) : part;
    var val = eq>-1 ? decodeURIComponent(part.substr(eq+1)) : "";
    var from = key.indexOf("[");
    if(from==-1) result[decodeURIComponent(key)] = val;
    else {
      var to = key.indexOf("]");
      var index = decodeURIComponent(key.substring(from+1,to));
      key = decodeURIComponent(key.substring(0,from));
      if(!result[key]) result[key] = [];
      if(!index) result[key].push(val);
      else result[key][index] = val;
    }
  });
  var re = /{(\w+)}/g;
  var results = [];
  while (match = re.exec(route)) {
      results.push(match[1]);
  }
  var re2 = /\/page1\/id\/(\w+)\/name\/(\w+)/g;
  var results2 = re2.exec(path);
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    result[results[i]] = results2[i + 1];
  }
  return result;
}
var route = "/page1/id/{id}/name/{name}";
var path = "/page1/id/23/name/leon?fname=Jon&lname=Doe";
var params = getParams(route, path);
console.log("PARAMS:", params);
```

The above code outputs:

```
PARAMS: Object {fname: "Jon", lname: "Doe", id: "23", name: "leon"}
```